bash case glob in order to match part of hostname and ignore last characters
we tested the following script - script.sh on machine hostname - presto-data1-01 , but seems the regex presto-data+([[:digit:]]) isn't good enough
machines hosts are as example:
presto-data1-01
presto-data1-02
presto-data1-03

or
presto-data2-01
presto-data2-02
presto-data2-03

etc
my script and example
more /tmp/script.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
hostname=$(hostname -s)


shopt -s extglob


case $hostname in

        presto+([[:digit:]]))
          bash /home/presto.sh;;

        presto-data+([[:digit:]]))
          bash /home/presto-data.sh;;
        *)  echo "Unrecognized hostname $hostname" ;;
esac


bash  /tmp/script.sh
Unrecognized hostname presto-data1-01

my machine name :
[root@presto-data1-01 # hostname -s
presto-data1-01

what we need to fix in regex - presto-data+([[:digit:]]) , in order to match as example the presto-data1  and ignore the characters after presto-data1 as "-01"

what should it not match?

Do you want to match presto01 and presto-data1 but not presto-data1-01 ? Or do you want a partial match in for presto-data1 in presto-data1-01 ?

we want a partial match in for presto-data1 , so even machine name is presto-data1-01 or  presto-data1-02 , etc then the regex will be match satisfied with presto-data1

here is example of full match - presto-data+([[:digit:]])?(-)+([[:digit:]]) , its works but as I explained we want true on partial match

so presto99abc should match?

should presta九七二 match?

I am talking about presto-data1 and actually presto-data[0-9]  , I update my question since details are confused

Do not confuse regex and glob patterns, you are using globs.

Use * to ignore last characters
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hostname=$(hostname -s)


shopt -s extglob


case $hostname in

        presto+([[:digit:]])*)
          bash /home/presto.sh;;

        presto-data+([[:digit:]])*)
          bash /home/presto-data.sh;;
        *)  echo "Unrecognized hostname $hostname" ;;
esac


Using read and parameter expansion
hostname='presto-data1-01'
IFS='-' read pr data id <<< "${hostname}"
echo "$pr '${data%%[0-9]}' $id"

if [ "${data%%[0-9]*}" == 'data' ];then
    echo "data host"
else
   echo "other"
fi

result
presto 'data' 01
data host

